# Is there a way to convert multiple date formats into datetime python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

Is there an easy way to convert multiple date formats into a datetime object in python? Eventually these will be inserted into a MySQL database with type DATE.

Examples of what type of data I might be receiving:

August 2, 2008

04-02-2007

May 2014

Converted I would like these to be:

2008-08-02

2007-04-02

2014-05-00

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to hard code each scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the third party [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("August 2, 2008")
datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 2, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("04-02-2007")
datetime.datetime(2007, 4, 2, 0, 0)
>>> parser.parse("May 2014")
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 0, 0)
```

Converting to required format:

```
>>> parser.parse("August 2, 2008").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2008-08-02'
>>> parser.parse("04-02-2007").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2007-04-02'
>>> parser.parse("May 2014").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2014-05-06'
```

You can install it with pip:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Also look at:

```
>>> parser.parse("May 2014")
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 0, 0)
>>> # As you wanted day to be 0 and that is not valid
...
>>> datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 0, 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
>>> # Workaround:
...
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datedefault = datetime.now().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> parser.parse("May 2014",default=datedefault).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2014-05-01'
```

If day is not specified in the date string and also no default is specified, it will take the current day. Since today is `06 Aug 2016`, it replaced the day to `0` in the first section of the answer for `"May 2014"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just want to confirm something: Why would May 2014 be parsed as having the 6th as the date?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to checkout [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser):

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dates = ['August 2, 2008', '04-02-2007', 'May 2014']
>>> [dateparser.parse(d, settings={'PREFER_DAY_OF_MONTH': 'first'}).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in dates]
['2008-08-02', '2007-04-02', '2014-05-01']
```

Plus side is you can specify to fill date with day missing (e.g. May 2014) to use either first day of the month, last or current.