# converting string to date some values are missing python

Tags: python, string, date

I want to be able to convert string to date format in python. But some of the day and month are assigned to 00.

```
date = ['00-00-2001', '10-01-2014']
```

when I tried :

`datetime.strptime(date[1], '%d-%m-%Y')`, of course it works fine,
but doing `datetime.strptime(date[0], '%d-%m-%Y')`, I get the following error.

> time data '00-00-2001' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'

Comment: What do you expect to get in case of a bad date?

Comment: Does 00-00-2001 really mean January 1, 2001, or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> %d    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.   01, 02, ..., 31
>
> %m    Month as a zero-padded decimal number.  01, 02, ..., 12

None of these accept `00` as valid string.

Also see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801552/1005215 which explains how you can use the `parser` from `dateutil` by passing a default parameter.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Telling the OP that it cannot be done is already taken care of by the Python interpreter.

Comment: @Kartik The python interpreter doesn't tell the OP why the string didn't match the format.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. "Telling the OP that it is not straightforward has already been done by the Python interpreter".

Answer (score 0):

Execute:

```
corrected_date = []
for d in dates:
    components = d.split('-')
    components = [str(c).zfill(2) if(int(c) > 0) else str(int(c) + 1).zfill(2) for c in components]
    corrected_date.extend(['-'.join(components)])
```

Now try your `strftime` on `corrected_date`.